# Is there a way to make an arbitary function timeout, in C?

Tags: c

I have a function that runs in C.  I would like for it to timeout, or at least be non blocking.  Is there a way to do that without running it as a thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select()` (or one of its platform-specific equivalents) is what should be used if you don't know that there is input available from a blocking file or socket, and want to continue if there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it nonblocking simply by making no blocking calls inside your function.  If you want it to time out, just wrap the non-blocking calls you're making in a little bit of code that gets and checks the time elapsed since the function was called.

Comment: By "a little bit of code" mean you "put it in a thread and have an outside thread monitor it and kill it if required", right?

Comment: Depends, I guess.  If you're only making nonblocking calls, you don't need extra threads.  By "a little bit of code" I meant something along the lines of `startTime = currentTime(); do { functions(); } while ((currentTime() - startTime) < timeout);`

Comment: i dont see how above code are "non-blocking" call.
the condition evaluation only happen after functions() returns...

Comment: If `functions()` is nonblocking, that code is nonblocking.  The original question was pretty vague; I think @Ignacio figured out what was being asked a lot better than I did.